# Hibernate: hide objects from query result

Tags: hibernate

I need an option to delete users from the site, however they should stay in the database for logs, and maybe at some point there will be a need to re-enable them. I can add a boolean variable to User class which will mean that this user was deleted, but my question is: Can I exclude these users from all my queries by default or should add restriction to all my queries to shown only users where deleted is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are talking about softdelete entities. Check Hibernate's @[SQLDelete](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLDelete.html) and @[Where](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html) annotations.